# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Univ#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I tried to list out the values of a specific table in the database using the following view file

index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag univ_path, method: :get do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>


<h1>List of Universities based on ranking</h1>
<div id="articles">
  <% @univ.each do |univ| %>
    <h2>
      <%= link_to univ.univ_name, univ %>
    </h2>
    <div class="info">
      <b>Location:</b> <%= univ.location %>, <%= univ.state %> <br/>
    </div>
    <br /><br />

    <div class="content"><p><%= univ.description %><p></div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

and the controller file is as follows

univ_controller.rb

```
class UnivController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if params[:query].present?      
      @univ= Univ.search(params[:query])
    else
      @univ=Univ.all
    end
  end

  def show
    @univ= Univ.find(params[:id])
  end

  def register
    @univ = Univ.new(params[:univ])
    if(request.post? and @univ.save)
      flash[:notice]= "Account Created Successfully"
      redirect_to :controller => 'univ', :action => 'register'
    end
  end
end
```

I was able to list out the contents of the table from db. However, when I include the form_tag for implementing search it results an error

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"univ"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

my routes.rb has

```
resources :univ get 'search' => "univ#index", :as => "search"
```

Please suggest necessary changes

Comment: @Graeme do you have any idea of how this can be resolved?

Comment: @emcanes that did not help. The error still exists

Comment: I use <%= simple_form_for :search, :url => search_path, :method => 'get' do |f| %>  ... you may also want to try and swap out univ_path to search_path as your as statement is :as => "search"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `form_for` in `index.html.erb` as below:

```
<%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>
```

I suppose you intended to submit the form on index action using the `search` route defined as:

```
get 'search' => "univ#index", :as => "search"
```

for that you would have to submit the form on `search_path`.

You are getting the error as `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"univ"} missing required keys: [:id]` because currently you are submitting the form on `univ_path` which would route to `show` action and therefore require an `id`.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem with a project I'm working on, and it turned out to be a Nil field in my database. Are you saving data to ruby sqlite?  Check for a record that has a nil [:id] and delete that record using Model.destroy(id) and you should be able to render the page again